Firestore missing or insufficient permissions using App Check
I am working on developping a nextjs website for myself and right now I am focusing on data.
It's a portfolio website, so no account needed.
My current problem is that I can't run my app using firestore with App Check runing.
The error I am facing is this one :
Erreur API Firestore : [Error [FirebaseError]: Missing or insufficient permissions.] {
  code: 'permission-denied',
  customData: undefined,
  toString: [Function (anonymous)]
}
 GET /api/api-handler?endpoint=cinema 500 in 78ms




To begining with a page called cinema.js :
import Nav from '@/components/Nav';
import Head from 'next/head';
import Footer from '@/components/Footer';
import Movie from '@/components/Movie';
import Link from 'next/link';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  try {
    const protocol = process.env.NODE_ENV === "production" ? "https" : "http";
    const host = context.req.headers.host;
    const response = await fetch(`${protocol}://${host}/api/api-handler?endpoint=cinema`);
    const data = await response.json();

    return {
      props: {
        projects: data,
      },
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Erreur lors de la récupération des données :", error);
    return {
      props: {
        projects: [],
      },
    };
  }
}

export default function Cinema({ projects }) {
  const [activeFilm, setActiveFilm] = useState(null);
  const [activeItem, setActiveItem] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div className="h-screen text-txt-default font-DM-Sans bg-bg-default bg-right-gradient p-6 flex flex-col justify-between select-none">
      <Head>
        <title>Cinéma</title>
      </Head>

      {/* Barre de navigation */}
      <div className="mb-6">
        <div className="flex justify-between projects-center">
          <div className="flex">
            <Link href="/" className="flex space-x-2 select-none" draggable="false">
              <h6 className="text-txt-default">Jacques</h6>
              <h6 className="text-txt-second">Tellier</h6>
            </Link>
          </div>
          <Nav />
        </div>
        {/* Titre principal */}
        <h2 className="text-accent select-none">CINÉMA</h2>
      </div>

      {/* Contenu principal */}
      <div className="flex flex-col 2xl:flex-row gap-8 2xl:my-20 mx-auto h-[75vh]">
        {/* Bloc des détails */}
        <div className="flex flex-col p-4 2xl:p-6 w-full 2xl:w-80 rounded-lg shadow-muted bg-bg-second order-first 2xl:order-none">
          {activeItem ? (
            <>
              <h4 className="text-txt-default mb-2 2xl:mb-4 text-base 2xl:text-lg">{activeItem.title}</h4>
              <p className="text-txt-muted text-sm 2xl:text-base">{activeItem.description}</p>
              <div className="mt-4 text-xs 2xl:text-sm">
                <p>
                  Année : <span className="text-txt-second">{activeItem.date}</span>
                </p>
                <p>
                  Genre :{" "}
                  <span className="text-txt-second">
                    {activeItem.genre.join(", ")}
                  </span>
                </p>
                <p>
                  Type :{" "}
                  <span className="text-txt-second">
                    {activeItem.type}
                  </span>
                </p>
                <p>
                  Réalisateur(s) : <span className="text-txt-second">{activeItem.director.join(", ")}</span>
                </p>
                <p>
                  Producteur(s) : <span className="text-txt-second">{activeItem.producer.join(", ")}</span>
                </p>
                <p>
                  Distribution :{" "}
                  <span className="text-txt-second">
                    {activeItem.distribution.join(", ")}
                  </span>
                </p>
                <br />
                <p>
                  Mon rôle :{" "}
                  <strong>
                    <span className="text-accent">{activeItem.role}</span>
                  </strong>
                </p>
              </div>
              <button
                onClick={() => setActiveFilm(activeItem)}
                className="mt-4 2xl:mt-10 px-4 2xl:px-6 py-2 2xl:py-3 bg-bg-inverse text-txt-inverse font-bold rounded-full hover:bg-bg-second hover:text-txt-default hover:shadow-inverse transition duration-100 select-none"
                draggable="false"
              >
                Voir +
              </button>
            </>
          ) : (
            <p className="text-txt-muted text-sm 2xl:text-base">Sélectionnez un élément pour afficher les détails.</p>
          )}
        </div>

        {/* Grille des affiches */}
        <div className="grid grid-cols-3 2xl:grid-cols-4 overflow-y-auto scrollbar-hide 2xl:gap-4 order-last 2xl:order-none">
          {projects.length > 0 ? (
            projects.map((item) => (
              <div
                key={item.id}
                className="flex flex-col rounded-lg p-4 hover:scale-105 transition-transform cursor-pointer"
                onClick={() => setActiveItem(item)}
              >
                <img
                  src={item.poster}
                  alt={item.title}
                  className="w-full h-32 2xl:h-64 object-cover rounded-md hover:shadow-inverse"
                />
                <div className="text-center mt-2 2xl:mt-4">
                  <h6 className="font-bold text-sm 2xl:text-base line-clamp-1">{item.title}</h6>
                  <p className="text-xs 2xl:text-sm text-txt-muted">{item.date}</p>
                </div>
              </div>
            ))
          ) : (
            <div className="col-span-full text-center text-lg text-txt-muted">
              Aucun projet pour le moment.
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>

      {/* Affichage de Movie en position absolue */}
      {activeFilm && (
        <Movie
          film={activeFilm}
          onClose={() => setActiveFilm(null)}
        />
      )}

      {/* Footer */}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

The API calls are beeing recieved here, in api-handler.js file :
import { collection, getDocs } from "firebase/firestore"; // Ajout de l'import manquant
import { db } from "@/config/firebase-config";

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  const { endpoint } = req.query; // Récupère le type de données demandé (ex : "cinema")

  if (req.method === "GET") {
    try {
      console.log("Requête reçue pour endpoint :", endpoint);

      const dataCollection = collection(db, endpoint); // Référencer la collection Firestore
      console.log("\n")
      console.log("Instance Firestore:", dataCollection._firestore);
      console.log("Chemin de la collection :", dataCollection._path.segments);
      console.log("Convertisseur :", dataCollection._converter);
      console.log("\n")
      const snapshot = await getDocs(dataCollection); // Récupérer les documents
      const data = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data(),
      }));

      console.log("Données récupérées :", data);
      res.status(200).json(data); // Retourne les données récupérées au client
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Erreur API Firestore :", error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Erreur lors de la récupération des données." });
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader("Allow", ["GET"]);
    res.status(405).end(`Méthode ${req.method} non autorisée`);
  }
}

And we are using this firebase-config.js file :
import { initializeApp, getApps, getApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
import { initializeAppCheck, ReCaptchaV3Provider } from "firebase/app-check";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
  databaseURL: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_DATABASE_URL, // Ajout de la configuration manquante
  measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID,
};

const app = !getApps().length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp();
const db = getFirestore(app);
const storage = getStorage(app);

if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  self.FIREBASE_APPCHECK_DEBUG_TOKEN = true;

  initializeAppCheck(app, {
    provider: new ReCaptchaV3Provider(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY),
    isTokenAutoRefreshEnabled: true, // Renouvelle automatiquement le jeton
  });
}

export { app, db, storage };

Here are the rules I am using on Firestore :
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  }
}

All is working when I turn off App check on the Firestore feature, I get my data, there is no errors, but ! I don't feel comfy without the app check on my app...
This is an example of one page with data included from firestore :
With App Check : https://i.sstatic.net/gYLvtztI.png
Without App Check : https://i.sstatic.net/pByvMAHf.png
App Check status when enforced : https://i.sstatic.net/p4VD3zfg.png

"I can't run my app using firestore with App Check runing" - what's the problem? Is there a specific error?  Please edit the question to be more clear about what isn't working the way you expect.  We should be able to take your code and instructions and use them to reproduce the problem.

Also note that: 1) none of the code you shared accesses Firestore yet, so none of it will actually trigger the rules you shared. Please include the minimal code that accesses Firestore and triggers the error. 2) Set your Firebase console to show in English (you can append ?hl=en to the URL to do that) and retake the screenshots, so that most folks here can more easily read what they say.,
